# How to set dimensions of TYPO3 RTE wizard?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tsconfig, rte

When adding a certain tyle of link in TYPO3 RTE. We always have to resize the wizard window because we can't see all the options on the right.

[image]

Is there a way to set the height and width of the RTE wizard in TYPO3 when adding a link ?

Current setup:
- TYPO3 7.6.23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code has to be inserted in the field "Page TSConfig" in the page-properties of the root-page, then the configuration is available for all pages.
After saving the windows to create / modify links have the defined size.
The numbers can be adjusted to the own needs but is then configured for all users.

```
RTE.default {
    buttons.link.dialogueWindow.width = 800
    buttons.link.dialogueWindow.height = 800
}
```

To adjust the windows related to further buttons the lines can be copied and then `link` has to be replaced by the name of the button.
A full list can be found here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rtehtmlarea/Configuration/PageTsconfig/interfaceConfiguration/Index.html#showbuttons

An explanation of all options related to `buttons.[ button-name ].dialogueWindow` can be found [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rtehtmlarea/Configuration/PageTsconfig/interfaceConfiguration/Index.html#buttons-button-name-dialoguewindow-width). Scroll down to see all the options, they're listed and explained one by one.